# PHP XML Post Request on WordPress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, soap

We are currently attempting to send XML data from our WordPress to a SOAP Service.

We have used ReadyAPI to test that the endpoint can receive data and it can so I am assuming that there is just something wrong with the code below.

This is code we have tried so far:

```
$url = $soapUrl;
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_body),
        "SOAPAction:http://foobarMethod"
    ); 

$tpn_send = wp_remote_post(
        $url, 
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => $xml_body,
        'sslverify' => false
    )
        );
```

We also tried doing it this way:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    // print "curl response is:" . $response; 
    curl_close($ch);
```

The response we received is blank. Additionally, the $url value is correct, just not included.

We are unsure what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to test getting response from your url in app like PostMan? Try it to be sure that response correctly. Or give your url to check.

Comment: We have used ReadyAPI to test instead of Postman. Our test on ReadyAPI is correct so I am assuming there is just something wrong with the code provided above

Comment: Just a heads up, this kind of response is better as a comment than an answer. Try to save answers for detailed solutions :)

Comment: so https://prnt.sc/KJlFMrVuALBQ :) can add answer but cant comment